# When should I accept links from other sites (SEO wise)?

Tags: seo, google, web-development, links

Instead of blogging in order to promote my site, I decided to form supporting professional sites. Each site is related to a specific keyword that I would like to promote on my main site.

My question is when should I add links from the supporting professional sites to my main site? Should I wait till the new sites will have PR?

My main fear is that the links from the new sites will damage my main site and reduce its PR...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, links can only increase your PageRank, not decrease it. But the potential problem here is that the new sites could be seen as spam, thus reducing their effect. It should also be noted that a handful of links, while helpful, is only a minor benefit.

However, if you do go down this route you are much better off building up a solid site first, before linking back to your main site. You don't have to wait until Google updates its PR toolbar but you'd need a couple of months.

Of course, if you are not careful this could become cyclical - now you need to increase the popularity/value of the second site to make the links worthwhile!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My main site is doing quite well. In some good keywords i'm in Google's top 5. I'm trying to strengthen the other keywords that i'm not doing so well. 

My thought was that building a 10 page website completely around a keyword will be promoted faster than adding another 10 pages to my 200 page website that is about 10 other keywords as well. Then I would add a couple of relevant links to the specific keyword in the main site. 

Do you agree?
If yes, should I add the links now or wait a couple of months?

By the way, I do agree about the cyclical effect...  :)

Comment: Honestly I don't think it will make a huge difference. If you already have an established site, you will do OK adding new content there, targeted to that keyword.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're creating microsites, building links to them and then linking from those microsites to your main site. Is that correct?

If it is, you're losing out on a tremendous amount of value. The current search engine algorithms have a strong emphasis on **domain diversity** - getting links from a number of relevant domains. By creating microsites, you lose out on all of that diversity.

In essence, you're generating more value for those microsites and only passing on a fraction of that value to the main site. You might consider creating landing pages (or subfolders) on the main site for this purpose so that you're building links directly to your main site.

Here's a decent video titled '[The Microsite Mistake](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/whiteboard-friday-the-microsite-mistake)' from Rand Fishkin via SEOmoz.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an intelligent black hat SEO.

If minor websites does not have active content, it will make no difference from link building farms we can find across the web.

I would suggest doing another way to build back links: social services.

Make a facebook page, invite people, bookmark on delicious and recommend to friends, make a short video on youtube with a backlink...

With this, you can provide quality backlinks. Once these sites are recognized as 'good' by google, the juice they pass back is a little better than from a completely new website, helping to improve your PR without too much effort and also in the other hand, can be a valuable tool for increasing visitors.